# How to prevent precision overflow in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM_PROPERTIES
( 
  ITEM_ID NUMERIC(11,0),
  ITEM_DIMENSIONAL_UOM VARCHAR(30),
  ITEM_HEIGHT NUMERIC(38,14),
  ITEM_WIDTH NUMERIC(38,14),
  ITEM_LENGTH NUMERIC(38,14),
  ITEM_WEIGHT_UOM VARCHAR(30),
  ITEM_WEIGHT NUMERIC(38,14),
  ITEM_CUBE NUMERIC(38,14)
);
```

The length/width/height of the items are stored in the table and I need to calculate the cube via the following SQL:

```
update ITEM_PROPERTIES set ITEM_CUBE = ITEM_WIDTH*ITEM_HEIGHT*ITEM_LENGTH
where ITEM_WIDTH<10000 and ITEM_HEIGHT < 10000 and ITEM_LENGTH<10000;
```

Then I encountered precision overflow:

```
ERROR: Resulting scale overflows maximum precision
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, this SQL works:

```
update ITEM_PROPERTIES set ITEM_CUBE = ITEM_WIDTH::decimal(12,3)*ITEM_HEIGHT::decimal(12,3)*ITEM_LENGTH::decimal(12,3)
where ITEM_WIDTH<10000 and ITEM_HEIGHT < 10000 and ITEM_LENGTH<10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [truncation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) maybe?

```
update ITEM_PROPERTIES set ITEM_CUBE = trunc(ITEM_WIDTH*ITEM_HEIGHT*ITEM_LENGTH, 14)
where
     ITEM_WIDTH<10000
     and ITEM_HEIGHT < 10000
     and ITEM_LENGTH<10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try rounding it or something to that order.

But the real problem stems from your types. If length, width and height are `numeric(38,14)`, the volume should be more like `numeric(114,42)`. And in fact a bit more, to accommodate for carries in the cases where the scale and precision are both used up in the three dimensions.

IMHO, get rid of the precision and scale entirely: store the numbers as `numeric` instead of `numeric(38,14)`, and avoid that the problem might arise in the first place. (If you *really* need 14 decimals, round it in your application or using a before trigger.)

Comment: That too, lol. :-) It's convenient for caching when indexes on expressions aren't available, that being said.